# Flutter Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable

I'm trying multiple request in a controller.

```
var requests = [];
for(var url in urls){
  requests.add(http.get(Uri.parse(url.split(',')[0])));
}

var results = await Future.wait(requests as Iterable<Future>);
for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
  saveData(urls[i].split(',')[1], results[i]);
}
```

So it give an error.

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Future>' in type cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Future.wait()` method expects an `Iterable<Future>` as an argument, but you're passing a `List` instead. Just remove casting:

```dart
  var requests = <Future>[];
  for (var url in urls) {
    requests.add(http.get(Uri.parse(url.split(',')[0])));
  }

  var results = await Future.wait(requests);
```

---

Or you can directly run for loop inside the argument:

```dart
  var results2 = await Future.wait([
    for (var url in urls) http.get(Uri.parse(url.split(',')[0])),
  ]);
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Two small changes needed:

1. Replace `var requests = [];` with `List<Future<dynamic>> requests = [];`
2. Replace `requests as Iterable<Future>` with `requests`